# Making JQuery work (linking the .js to the .html)

Tags: jquery, button

I am struggling with the most basic of JQuery magic: making it work. I had a much bigger JQuery file with some (previously) functional javascript, but my problem persisted even when I boiled it down to simply a page with a button that once clicked is supposed to fade out. I can only suppose I am referencing wrongly.

This is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Make me vanish!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my script.js

```
$(document).ready(){
$('button').onclick(function(){
    $('button').fadeOut('fast');
});});
```

This is the link to the test-page itself(not working): http://folk.ntnu.no/benjamas/test.html

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! My problem is now solved thanks to your wonderful help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to load jQuery before any scripts that uses jQuery :

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

And you do know that you're only including jQuery UI, and not the library itself ?

And your JS should look like :

```
$(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh, no I did actually not know that. Thanks for editing my code. I was just about to ask you a follow-up question as someone had already answered that below. Thanks you guys!

Comment: All my knowledge comes from the first course of the codeacadamy site, and there I always have to start with $(document).ready(); Why did this code only work once I got rid of that?

Comment: @BenjaminS, it's not that it would only work without it, but rather that you wrote it incorrectly.  adeneo's  `$(function(){` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function () {`.  You had left out the `function () {` bit.

Comment: oh my, that is such an obvious mistake it's as if it's screaming at me!

Answer (score 5):

You are missing jQuery itself. That, and you need to reverse the order of your script tags, as your `script.js` depends on `jQuery` (it actively uses the `$` symbol).

Try this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

In addition, your JS itself is dubious - you either use the DOM `onclick` handler, or you use `jQuery`'s `$.click()`. Not a mixture of both.

Answer (score 2):

Your script has errors, here's a working one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('button').fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1st: Add the jQ library itself:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then in the code try this:

```
<input class="button">Make me vanish!</input>
```

...

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    $('.button').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

It does not have to be inside the $(document) object iirc; this is a "listener" of sorts.

Comment: Why are you wrapping a form around the button?  There doesn't seem to be anything to suggest that there should be a form on the page!